# Is there a way to get `self` where method is executed?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
class Foo
  def run(scope:)
     p scope
  end
end

module Bar
  Foo.run(scope: self) # >> Bar
end

Foo.run(scope: self) # >> main
```

I want to do something like:

```
module Bar
  Foo.run
end

Foo.run
```

with the same results. Is there a way to get the `self` of where the method is called without explicitly mentioning it?

Comment: Are you looking for [`caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller)?

Comment: Are yes. That's what I'm looking for. Thanks.